# Wrap elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using AJAX with jQuery to get some html content and here's the success function:

```
function successFn(data) {

    var keyWord = $("#input").val();

    // convert string html to object
    var anchors = $('<div/>').html(data).contents();

    // add data-keyword to all results
    anchors.each( function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-keyword', keyWord);
        $(this).wrap('<div class="xXx"></div>');
    });

    // print results
    $("#results").html(anchors);
}
```

The `data` contains a a list of anchors:

```
<a href="link">...children...</a>
<a href="link">...children...</a>
<a href="link">...children...</a>
<a href="link">...children...</a>
```

So i'm trying to add an attribute to these links, which is working  Then I wrap each anchor with a div, which is not working.

Why isn't it wrapping?

Comment: What does not working mean? Does the final result just not have those wrapping divs?

Comment: It seems to work.  Can you create a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @Jordan, FakeRainBrigand, exactly what I meant... the final ouptut doesnt have the a wrapped... anyway, epascarello solved that for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are only adding the anchor elements, you are not including the content that you wrapped.

```
function successFn(data) {

    var keyWord = $("#input").val();

    // convert string html to object
    var wrapper = $('<div/>').html(data);
    var anchors = wrapper.contents();

    // add data-keyword to all results
    anchors.each( function (i) {
        $(this).attr('data-keyword', keyWord);
        $(this).wrap('<div class="xXx"></div>');
    });

    // print results
    $("#results").empty().append(wrapper.contents());
}
```

Comment: I knew it was that the problem... but since I'm new to JS, i couldnt correct it... Thanks for this fast reply :)